# Is there a non-piece-wise representation of the Bernoulli CDF?

Tags: statistics

When doing a related homework problem I was curious to know if there is a way to represent the CDF of a Bernoulli distribution as a non-piece-wise function (I say this because I doesn't feel right to call a function of a binary variable 'continuous'). My motivation for doing this is to see if I can then invert said function, and use for generating random variates.

To be clear, it is intuitively obvious to me that I can generate random variates using the uniform distribution (e.g. $0 < R_i < 1$), by returning 1 if $R_i < p$ or 0 if $R_i \ge p$, but I don't know how we come to this conclusion mathematically.

If I begin with the non-piece-wise definition of the PMF from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution):

$$
  f(k;p) = p^k(1-p)^{1-k}
$$

Through a little manipulation I can show:

$$
   f(k;p) = (1-p)\left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right)^k=(1-p)e^{k \mathrm{ln}\left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right)}
$$

Both of these forms seem valid (i.e. they give the correct results for $k=0,1$). From here, I tried to integrate this function to get the CDF:

$$
    F(k;p) = \frac{1-p}{\mathrm{ln}\left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right)}e^{k \mathrm{ln}\left( \frac{p}{1-p} \right)}
$$

This does not agree with Wikipedia's piece-wise  definition of the Bernoulli CDF (i.e. yields incorrect results for $k=0,1$.)

My intuition tells me that the binary nature of the dependent variable $k$ violates some fundamental assumptions required for it's straightforward integration.

I'm hoping that someone can:

1. show how the PDF can be integrated and (if possible) inverted or,
2. construct a suitable non-piece-wise CDF or,
3. explain why I can't represent the CDF in this way.

Comment: You need to distinguish between discrete distributions (such as the binomial) and continuous distributions (such as the normal). Discrete distributions put all probability on a finite or countable number of individual points. Continuous distributions assign probabilities only to intervals. Density functions of some continuous distributions can be integrated to get an algebraic expression for their cumulative distribution functions. Sorry, but it makes no sense at all to speak of 'integrating' the PMF of a discrete distribution. (More could be said, but not within space allocated to a comment.)

Comment: @BruceTrumbo It is a discrete distribution. How do we relate the PMF to the CDF of a discrete random variable if not through integration?

Comment: I'm afraid "tediously" is the usual answer. Often tables of CDFs of common distributions are available (for selected parameter values) in the back of some textbooks. For a binomial you might have $F_X(2) = P(X \leq 2) = P(X = 0) + P(X = 1) + P(X = 2).$  Also, $F_X(3) - F_X(2) = P(X = 3),$ and so on. Some calculators and software has built-in PMF and CDF software. In R (free from r-project.org): For X ~ BIN(3,.5), pbinom(2, 3, .5) returns 0.875, and dbinom(2, 3, .5) returns 0.375. (Probability functions beginning with p are CDFs, beginning with d are PMFs.)